# How to solve linearization to approximate $\sqrt[3]{61}$. to the nearest ten thousandth

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

I'm not sure what the nearest ten-thousandth place means in the question above.

How can I solve this problem step by step?

Comment: Accurate to $a.bcde$

Comment: What does this mean exactly?

Comment: Nearest ten thousandth place means that you should get a value that matches the value of $\sqrt[3]{61}$, rounded to $4$ decimal places. The actual answer is $\sqrt[3]{61} = 3.93649718...$, so you are expected to get $3.9365...$ for an answer. As for the question itself, what methods of approximation (Taylor / binomial expansion etc.) do you know?

Comment: Newton-Raphson, linear interpolation?

Comment: I'm in Calculus 2 right now! I'm helping a friend right now all I know is that if the question was asked without  the last part "To the nearest ten thousand" I would compare the 61^(1/3) to 60^(1/3)

Comment: Use newton-raphson: $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac {f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ and take $\sqrt[3] 64=4$ as $x_0$

Comment: I'm not sure what newton-raphson is?

Comment: It is a form of rapid approximation. Use the formula to find an approximation to ten-thousandths rapidly.

Comment: The way to use linearization is as follows : given $f$ differentiable,  a number $x$ for which $f(x)$ is to be found. What we should do, is find a number $a$ very close to $x$, and then use the approximation $f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a) \times (x-a)$. For example, if we have $x = 61$, then take $a = 64$ (of course, $f(x) =x^{\frac 13}$) to get $\sqrt[3](61) \approx 4 + f'(64) \times (-3)$. $f'$ here is $\frac 13 x^{-\frac 23}$, which at $64$ is $\frac 1{48}$. So the answer is approximately $4 - \frac 1{16} = 3 \frac{15}{16}$. Take better $a$ for better approximation.

Comment: Or go into the second order approximation, as the below answer does. That is a step further than "linearization" , nevertheless it does a better job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use linearization you need to identify an appropriate function and a point to linearize that function.

The function $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ seems appropriate, and you can evaluate $f(64)$ directly. The linearization of $f$ at $a = 64$ is given by
$$y = f(64) + f'(64)(x-64).$$
Since $f'(x) = \dfrac 13 x^{-2/3}$ you have $f(64) = 4$ and $f'(64) = \dfrac 1{3 \cdot 16}$ so that the approximation with $x=61$ is
$$y = 4 + \dfrac 1{3 \cdot 16} (61-64) = 4 - \frac 1{16} = 3.9375.$$

The actual value is pointed out in the comments, so the linearization doesn't give you enough decimal places. Since you are in Calc 2 you have probably seen Taylor's theorem, so instead you should try the second order approximation
$$y = f(64) + f'(64)(x-64) + \frac{f''(64)}{2}(x-64)^2$$ and see what that yields.

Comment: Aweseom! Thank you so much!

Comment: How did you know to use 64 as a value?

Comment: I looked for numbers near 61 that are perfect cubes. As stated in the solution "you can evaluate $f(64)$ directly".

Comment: Yeah, I understand that you need to find a perfect cube but why do you need to find a perfect cub versus using values that are much closer to 61. Values like 60 or values much closer like 61.001.

Comment: How would you determine the value of $(60)^{1/3}$ to perform the linearization?

Comment: Yeah! I'm definitely missing some fundamentals of linearization. I just don't see how you found the insight or how you know that you need to compare 61^(1/3) to a perfect cubed such as 64^(1/3).   So I guess my question is what is the overall goal of linearization?  And for future reference how should I look at this problem to know that I need to find a perfect cubed root to compare to my given value.